# Laravel bind to tables with belongsTo

Tags: laravel-4, model-binding

I want to bind to tables with relationships. One table is `posts` and second table is `users`. In the posts table have `user_id`.

How can I do this?

Comment: please add the code what have you done so far??

Comment: u cant write question like that we need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Post model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

If you need reverse relationship, on your User model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```